# NSURLConnection with https and TLS 1.1

Tags: macos, cocoa, ssl, nsurlconnection, tls1.2

My app uses NSURLConnection to post an xml file to a financial organization in my country that will at some point next year stop using SSL protocols and switch to TLS 1.1 or 1.2.

My app is linked to 10.6 SDK as many of my clients use older systems. There are several questions I like to ask and I am not sure how this all affects me.

Does it matter to what SDK am I linked? If my app is used on latest Mac OS will NSURLConnection use latest TLS by default? How do I test the TLS version on a system?

Should I link to the newer SDK? Or just tell affected clients to upgrade to Mountain Lion or newer?

The problem is I can't test anything now as the organization in question just announced that at some point in 2016. they'll stop support for anything less than TLS 1.1.

Comment: I mentioned Mountain Lion because I found this link: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2012-08/0120.html and it was the only place I could find specifying TLS version on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to keep yourself confined to an ancient version of Xcode (I think Xcode 3?), what you can do is use the latest version of Xcode and

1)

[specify MacOS 10.6 as the "minimum deployment version"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW21)

(honestly, in my opinion, you should only support 1 - 3 MacOS versions back... MacOS 10.6 dates from 2011).

2)

[And make sure to use app transport security exceptions to allow for older TLS](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/) under MacOS 10.11 and newer MacOS versions.

Apple will happily support TLS 1.2 going forward.  If you still need to support TLS 1.1, that'll still require an exception in the app's info.plist file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to specify deployment and this is probably how I'm going to handle this whole thing. Yet at the same time this raises a question I never asked myself. When Apple fix a bug or patch a problem in one OS version, they fix it only for fresh applications linked to the latest SDK. Is that true? So if anyone is using an old app he's still vulnerable to whatever there was at the time.

Comment: Oh, and about the Xcode. I have the 3.6 in a VMWare. Using it for my Carbon things and strange legacy code.

Comment: Actually - when Apple fixes a bug in any of their system components (security and encryption components included) you gain this fix automatically, even in your older Apps, without re-compiling and re-linkning them. Your code merely calls the (external) system service. MacOS is not using static libs which get copied into your app.